# stagexl frame-rate independent logic

Tags: dart, game-loop, stagexl

I have created a controller which listens to onKeyUp and onKeyDown events and updates a map of keys (bit set actually). It also listens to onEnterFrame event, upon which it checks which keys are down at the moment and takes actions. Everything works, but since the app is running 60 frames/second, my input is also updated 60 times/second. I'd like to have the input only updated, say 30 times/second and have that speed independent from the display speed.

To generalize my problem, where do I put the update logic, so that it runs independently of the display frame rate (which is what happens using onEnterFrame).

The StageXL documentation isn't much of a help at the moment. **I am aware of how this is done, by measuring the time since last frame**, but I expect that such a high-level framework as StageXL will have a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the Juggler Framework that is built into StageXL. It is a freamework to do time-based animations. It also works great with streams as you know it from the Dart language.

You can learn more about it here:
http://www.stagexl.org/docs/wiki-articles.html?article=juggler

And most of the examples here are using the Juggler too:
https://github.com/bp74/StageXL_Samples

Btw. the Juggler was invented by the author of the Startling framework and was later ported to StageXL.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! The Juggler framework is wonderful for state control!